# Set counter for tcolorbox environment in beamer

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, counters

Please help me to put a simple counter in the `tcolorbox` environment in `beamer`. It only needs to go from 1,2,3,...

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!5,colframe=green!40!black, center,title=    ]

\end{tcolorbox}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the key `auto counter` for that purpose. As it turns out, it does not yet automatically harmonize with `beamer` `\pause`s. This can be fixed by redefining `\tcb@proc@counter@auto` to become

```
\def\tcb@proc@counter@auto#1{%
  \newcounter{tcb@cnt@#1}%
  \csxdef{tcb@cnt@#1}{tcb@cnt@#1}%
  \tcb@proc@counter@autoanduse{#1}%
  \ifcsname resetcounteronoverlays\endcsname%<-added
  \resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@#1}%<-added
  \fi%<-added
}
```

So the MWE becomes

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\def\tcb@proc@counter@auto#1{%
  \newcounter{tcb@cnt@#1}%
  \csxdef{tcb@cnt@#1}{tcb@cnt@#1}%
  \tcb@proc@counter@autoanduse{#1}%
  \ifcsname resetcounteronoverlays\endcsname%<-added
  \resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@#1}%<-added
  \fi%<-added
}
\makeatother
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{numberedbox}[2][]{%
colback=green!5,colframe=green!40!black,center,title=Numbered
box~\thetcbcounter: #2,#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{tcolorboxes}
\begin{numberedbox}[label={boxA}]{title A}
I am random box and have number~\ref{boxA}
\end{numberedbox}
\pause
\begin{numberedbox}[label={catinbox}]{A cat in a box}
\dots wrote this, see numbered box~\ref{boxA}
\end{numberedbox}
\pause
\begin{numberedbox}[label={yetanotherbox}]{title B}
I'm boring, see numbered box~\ref{catinbox} for something exciting
\end{numberedbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Schrodinger's cat. It works and yet a very simple solution!

Comment: Although this solution works, but I encountered another problem when I use it with the \pause command. The counter keeps counting up for the same box. Is there a way to make the counter not to count the same box more than once?

Comment: @hochoi Good point! I added a working solution. Even though there is a section on beamer support in the tcolorbox manual, I could not find anything on `auto counter` support. Since `tcolorbox` gives it some internal name that is not obvious, I added a normal counter here. Maybe that would be something for a feature request to ask to make `auto counter` do that automatically.

Comment: It works wonderfully! Thank you very much, @Schrodinger's cat!

Comment: One more problem popping up :) How do I refer to certain box? The label command does not seem o be able to track the counter accurately.

Comment: @hochoi OK OK, I tried to fix it once and for all by slightly redefining an internal command of `tcolorbox`.  It adds the counter to the reset list *if* the `\resetcounteronoverlays` command is defined, which should be a very good check whether or not that's a `beamer` document.

Comment: Thank again, Schrodinger's cat. You are always a big help. I will test this one tomorrow and confirm :)

Comment: Things work as intended now. Thank you so much for your effort, Schrodinger's cat.

Comment: @hochoi You are welcome! I think you raised an important point, see https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/80#issuecomment-536969328.

Comment: I am glad I did without real intention :) I am curious on the \makeatletter and \makeatother. It seems that you can remove the \makeatother?

Comment: @hochoi Any attempt of me answering this will be pale compared to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8353/194703, so just read Alan's answer on this. ;-)

Comment: I see. Thank again, @Schordinger's cat.

Comment: Hi Schrodinger'scat, there is a need for an improvement in the codes. That is, when I try to refer certain box, the label of the box is not listed for me to choose from when I type \ref{. Is it possible to make that happen?

Comment: @hochoi Could you add a concrete example to the question? Or, perhaps even better, ask a new question with that examples which many users will see?

Comment: Will do so. Thanks, Schrödinger's cat.